# Create and initialize 5x5 grid for Battleships

Tags: python, list, grid, initialization

So I just completed a section of CodeAcademy Battleship problem, and have submitted a correct answer but am having trouble understanding why it is correct.

The idea is to build a 5x5 grid as a board, filled with "O's". The correct code I used was:

```
board = []
board_size=5

for i in range(board_size):

    board.append(["O"] *5)
```

However I'm confused as to why this didn't create 25 "O's" in one single row as I never specified to iterate to a separate row. I tried

```
for i in range(board_size):

    board[i].append(["O"] *5)
```

but this gave me the error: `IndexError: list index out of range`. Can anyone explain why the first one is correct and not the second one?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
["O"]*5
```

This creates a list of size 5, filled with "O": `["O", "O", "O", "O", "O"]`

```
board.append(["O"] *5)
```

This appends (adds to the end of the list) the above list to board[].  Doing this 5 times in a loop creates a list filled with 5 of the above lists.

```
[["O", "O", "O", "O", "O"],
["O", "O", "O", "O", "O"],
["O", "O", "O", "O", "O"],
["O", "O", "O", "O", "O"],
["O", "O", "O", "O", "O"]]
```

Your code did not work, because lists are not initialized with a size in python, it just starts as an empty container `[]`.  To make yours work, you could have done:

```
board = [[],[],[],[],[]]
```

and in your loop:

```
board[i] = ["O"]*5
```

Answer (score 2):

Python lists start out empty:

```
board = [] # empty list
```

Unlike some programming languages, you do not specify or initialise the bounds of the array, so if you try to access by index:

```
board[0]
```

you will get an `IndexError`; there is not yet any index `0`.

In the first version, on each trip through the `for` loop, you `append` (add to the end of the list) a *new list* containing five `"O"`s. If you want the `board` list to contain 25 `"O"`s, you should use `extend` instead:

```
for i in range(board_size):
    board.extend(["O"] *5)
```

Answer (score 1):

Code should look like this.

`board = []
for i in range(0, 5):
    board.append(["O"]*5)
print(board)`

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is simple: when you run your code, your array is empty!

You could issue a

```
board = [[], [], [], [], []]
```

to initialize it as a nested, five places array.

You could also use a dict to simulate a indefinitely nested array:

```
board=defaultdict(lambda:defaultdict(lambda:[]))
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because each time you run `board.append(["O"] *5)` you create a new list (because of the square brackets used inside the append statement).

If you would have used `board.append("O" *5)` instead the you would get a single list with five elements like:

> ['OOOOO', 'OOOOO', 'OOOOO', 'OOOOO', 'OOOOO']

The *5 multiplies the string. if you just run from an interactive prompt `'O' * 5` you get:

> 'OOOOO'

However, if you run `['O'] * 5` it multiplies the text within the list and you get a list with five elements.

> ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O']

You appended five lists, each having 5 elements.

Answer (score 0):

```
board = []
board_size=5

for i in range(board_size):

    board.append(["O"] *5)
```

In this code `board` starts as an empty list. `["O"] * 5` will create a list that is equal to `["O", "O", "O", "O", "O"]`. It will then be appended to the list `board`. This will happen 5 times in this example since `board_size == 5`.

```
for i in range(board_size):

    board[i].append(["O"] *5)
```

This wouldn't work unless the item at index `i` was a list since `append()` is a method of the `list` class. If you wanted to insert something at `i` you would use the list method `insert()`

Answer (score 0):

First step  in codeacademy

```
board = []
for i in range(5):
    board.append(["O"]*5)

print board
```

Second step  in codeacademy

```
board = []

def print_board(board):
    for x in range(5):
        board= (["O"] * 5)
        print board
    return board

print_board(board)
```

third step in codeacademy

```
board = []

def print_board(board):
    for x in range(5):
        board= (["O"] * 5)
        print " ".join(board)
    return board

print_board(board)
```

4th Step

```
from random import randint 

board = []

for x in range(0, 5):
    board.append(["O"] * 5)

def print_board(board):
    for row in board:
        board = " ".join(row)
        return  board

def random_row(board):
    return randint(0, len(board) - 1)

def random_col(board):
    return randint(0, len(board) - 1)

print print_board(board)
print random_row(board)
print random_col(board)
```

5th step of buttleship on codeacademy

```
from random import randint

board = []

for x in range(0,5):
    board.append(["O"] * 5)

def print_board(board):
    for row in board:
        print " ".join(row)

def random_row(board):
    return randint(0, len(board) - 1)

def random_col(board):
    return randint(0, len(board[0]) - 1)

ship_row = random_row(board)
ship_col = random_col(board)


guess_row = int(raw_input("Guess Row: "))
guess_col = int(raw_input("Guess Col: "))
```

## Final Step Lets .. Play game BettleShip CodeAcademy

```
from random import randint
```

board = []
for x in range(5):
    board.append(["O"] * 5)

def print_board(board):
    for row in board:
        print " ".join(row)

print "Let's play Battleship!"
print_board(board)

def random_row(board):
    return randint(0, len(board) - 1)

def random_col(board):
    return randint(0, len(board[0]) - 1)

ship_row = random_row(board)
ship_col = random_col(board)
print ship_row
print ship_col

turns=0
win = 0
for turn in range(4):
    if turn <= 5:
        guess_row = int(raw_input("Guess Row:"))
        guess_col = int(raw_input("Guess Col:"))

```
    if guess_row == ship_row and guess_col == ship_col:
        print "Congratulations! You sunk my battleship!"
        win +=1
        if win == 2:
            break
    else:
        turns +=1
        if (guess_row < 0 or guess_row > 4) or (guess_col < 0 or guess_col > 4):
            print "Oops, that's not even in the ocean."
        elif(board[guess_row][guess_col] == "X"):
            print "You guessed that one already."
        else:
            print "You missed my battleship!"
            board[guess_row][guess_col] = "X"
            print (turn + 1)
        print_board(board)
elif turns == 3:
    print "Game Over"
else:
    print "Max Turn try is over Try Again"
```