# Codecademy battleship function

Tags: python

I am supposed to create a `5x5` grid of `['O']`s.

I tried the following code:

```
board = []
def filler(x):
  c = ['O'] * 5
  for i in c:
    board.append(i)
    print (c)
filler(c)
```

Which creates the 5x5 grid that they ask for. What I can't figure out is why is the grid not being added to board?

Is there something wrong with my for loop? I looked at this [page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21434430/codeacademy-battleship) and noticed that no one suggests a function, which is something I also don't understand.

Is a function not appropriate for this exercise (or is it just my function that isn't appending correctly?)

Comment: Should you not be getting an error for the variable `c` not being defined while calling `filler(c)` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That doesn't create a 5x5 grid. You first create a flat `list` of `['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O']`, then you iterate over it and append each element to the board, making `board` an equal `list`. The `x` parameter in the function is never used.

You should throw the whole thing out and just do this:

```
def create_board(size):
    return [['O' for column in range(size)] for row in range(size)]

board = create_board(5)
```

This uses nested comprehensions to create a 2D `list` of the size you want.

Demo:

```
>>> for row in board:
...     print(*row)
...
O O O O O
O O O O O
O O O O O
O O O O O
O O O O O
```

Comment: xrange is more efficient. range create list. when size will too large xrange would be helpful.

Comment: @SaifulIslam - Did the question or this answer look like Python 2 to you? The `print(*row)` in particular is a sure sign that we're using Python 3 here.

Comment: No problem. In the future, I recommend simply commenting with a request for clarification rather than substantively modifying someone's code in a suggested edit.