# How do I make a 5x5 list?

Tags: python, list, grid

I tried with for loops, but I just get  5   1   2   1   1   4   1   2   2   4   2   1   5   2   4   5   4   2   3   2   4   5   3   2   3   instead of an actual 5x5 grid. 
*(just so you know the context:I am later supposed to create a dictionary whose keys are the random numbers from 5x5 list and whose values are the how many times the number occurs and then print the three most common numbers.)*

```
from random import randint
for i in range(1,6):
    for j in range(1,6):
            print("{:3d}".format(randint(1,5)),end=" ")
```

Comment: *to create a dictionary* - you are not creating any dictionary. Update your code due to your actual intention

Comment: If you just want to print a 5x5 grid, just add a `print("\n")` after the inner loop.

Comment: Check this out to understand how to initialize 5X5 grid https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21434430/create-and-initialize-5x5-grid-for-battleships/21434522

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple to use list comprehension to create 5x5 list

```
from random import randint
n = 5
grid = [[randint(1, 5) for _ in range(n)] for i in range(n)]

print(grid)
```

**Output**

```
[[5, 3, 3, 5, 5], [3, 2, 4, 3, 3], [3, 3, 3, 3, 4], [3, 4, 5, 3, 3], [5, 4, 1, 2, 3]]
```

**Explanation**

We're creating a list of lists

Create an inner nested list of n elements (inner for loop)

```
[randint(1, 5) for _ in range(n)]
```

Stack the inner lists (looping over i)

```
[[...] for i in range(n)]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import random
import itertools
import operator
five_dim = [[random.randint(1,5) for b in range(0,5)]for a in range(0,5)]
flat_list = [num for num in itertools.chain(*five_dim)]
key_set = set(flat_list)
freq_dict ={k: flat_list.count(k) for k in key_set}
x= sorted(freq_dict.items(), key = operator.itemgetter(0))[0:3]
print(x)
```

### Steps:-

1. First create 5 X 5 grid
2. Create flatten list from the list of lists(5 x 5 grid)
3. Create a dictionary, set of random numbers from the grid as a key and frequency of each number as value
4. Sort the dictionary value in ascending order and return the three most frequent one, as a list of tuple, (key, value) pair.